# Connecting to SQL Server from Ubuntu VM in Rails 3.2 with tinytds

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, virtualbox, tiny-tds

I have a Windows 7 machine with an Ubuntu 11.10 vm running inside it with VirtualBox. On my Windows 7 machine I have SQL Server 2008 installed which I am trying to access from my Ubuntu vm using rails 3.2 and the tiny_tds gem.

When I try to start my rails application I get the following:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68:in `connect': Unable to open socket (TinyTds::Error)
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68:in `initialize'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:415:in `new'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:415:in `connect'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:203:in `initialize'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:40:in `new'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:40:in `sqlserver_connection'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:277:in `new_connection'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:287:in `checkout_new_connection'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:235:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `loop'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `block in checkout'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__855141609__prepare__585695355__callbacks'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/user/RubymineProjects/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/RubymineProjects/myapp/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /home/user/RubymineProjects/myapp/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/user/RubymineProjects/myapp/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I can verify that SQL Server is accessible to the vm by running telnet to my host ip on port 1433 and I am able to connect successfully, but for whatever reason I can't connect via ruby or TinyTds. My network adapter for my vm is using NAT. Furthermore, if I run that same rails application from my Windows machine I can connect to SQL Server. TCP/IP connections are enabled for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the `dataserver` setting to `host` instead and that fixed it.

Comment: In the yaml configuration, I changed renamed the `dataserver` setting to `host`.